# Intercept image visualizer and start app

Tags: android

I have an app running in background, and now I want to intercept the image visualizer app of Android and when an image is opened I want the app to do something.

Which way can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create new `Activity`, then go to your `AndroidManifest`, define `intent-filter`

```
    <activity android:name="YourActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```